# Display multiline text in cell that can expand collapse in Ag Grid?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-ng2

Is there any way to create multi-row text in AG Grid and that could be expand/collapse feature (similar to grouped row).

Example of what I am looking for can be found in RapidMiner - Statistics feature:

[image: RapidMiner]

Answer (score 0):

This is possible. In my example, I have defined `dataRenderer` to handle custom cell renderig.

An extra column 'Toggle' is used to fire the event that will change content of chosen cell and apply row height using function `toggleRenderer`.

```
{
  headerName: "Toggle",
  field: " ",
  hide: false,
  width: 80,
  cellRenderer: toggleRenderer //action button for expand/collapse action
}
```

Custom button display in the grid:

```
  function toggleRenderer(params) {
    params.$scope.toggleRow = toggleRow;
    return '<button ng-click="toggleRow()"> > </button>';
  }
```

Main collapse/expand action:

```
function toggleRow() {
    //get current row
    var row = this.rowNode; 

    //toggle selection
    var selected = !row.selected;

    //change the row height regarding if row is selected or not
    var height = selected ? 75 : 25; 

    //apply changes
    row.setRowHeight(height);
    row.setSelected(selected);

    var params = {
      force: true,
      rowNodes: [row]
    };

    //update display
    $scope.gridOptions.api.refreshCells(params);
    $scope.gridOptions.api.onRowHeightChanged();
  }
```

Important part of the code, responsible for multiline display:

```
{
   ...
   cellRenderer: dataRenderer
}

function dataRenderer(params) {
    if (params.node.selected) {
      //you can place here any display (chart or other) that will be shown on expand
      return (
        "<div>Row1: " +
        params.data.price +
        ...
        "<div>RowXX:" +
        params.data.price +
        "</div>"
      );
    } else {
      return params.data.price;
    }
}
```

[Here is the working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-snowflake-mfg7t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)